# Is it okay to filter using code instead of the NoSQL database?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql

We are using DynamoDB and have some complex queries that would be very easily handled using code instead of trying to write a complicated DynamoDB scan operation. Is it better to write a scan operation or just pull the minimal amount of data using a query operation (query on the hash key or a secondary index) and perform further filtering and reduction in the calling code itself? Is this considered bad practice or something that is okay to do in NoSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it depends.

If you have an even modestly large table a table scan is not practical.

If you have complicated query needs the best way to tackle that using DynamoDB is using Global Secondary Indexes (GSIs) to act as projections on the fields that you want.  You can use techniques such as sparse indexes (creating a GSI on fields that only exist on a subset of the objects) and composite attributes keys (concatenating two or more attributes and using this as a new attribute to create a GSI on).

However, to directly address the question "Is it okay to filter using code instead of the NoSQL database?" the answer would be yes, that is an acceptable approach.  The reason for performing filters in DynamoDB is not to reduce the "cost" of the query, that is actually the same, but to decrease unnecessary data transfer over the network.

The ideal solution is to use a GSI to get to reduce the scope of what is returned to as close to what you want as possible, but if it is necessary some additional filtering can be fine to eliminate some records either through a filter in DynamoDB or using your own code.